# Mahwa with duplicate main characters - one is weak and other is strong and they both change their world

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

Manhwa Murim in which blue/dark blue haired student who is weak is bullied by people in front of a girl. He is transferred to another world or past in Murim. His duplicate is transferred to his world, and calls the girl the princess. The girl also started liking the new boy. The boy fights the guys easily and saves the girl. The next day they go to school.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, what were the names of the protagonists? Where are you likely to have read this? Did you read it in English or the original language? What was the name of the girl? What did she look like? What kind of fighting was it? What is the setting of the world (fantasy, realistic)? Was he literally duplicated? Who did the transfering? Was there magic in this world? Is this manhwa aimed at adults (with sex, nudity, gore, violence) or at general audiences? What kind of school was it? Who was making him go to school?

Comment: [***Immortal, Invincible?***](https://page.kakao.com/content/47784012) MC gets duplicated and reincarnated at the same time;

Comment: By "duplicate" do you mean "alternate version of himself" (like as in 'multiverse')?

Comment: No it was for general audiences. Alternate version of himself, and he thinks the girl infront of him is a princess/majesty, she was princess in alternate world. It was Korean Manhwa and long strip form of comic. In the alternate world the weak boy shifted.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *[The Star of a Supreme Ruler](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/star-of-the-overlord)* (AKA *The Star of the Overlord*)?

> With the appearance of the Overlord’s Star in the sky, the world plunges into chaos, and only the one born with the essence of the star can save it. Amidst the upheaval, former comrades Baek Woonhoi and Chun Ryuyoung each dream of becoming the Overlord. Ryuyoung to save his family, and Woonhoi because he has nothing else to lose. But as the star shines brighter, the two find themselves swept up in an impending war. Both men’s ambitions burn fiercely, but only one Overlord can reign supreme!
>
> [image]

This [reddit review](https://www.reddit.com/r/manhwa/comments/watno4/is_there_a_murim_manhwa_with_a_weak_mc_or_one/) is pretty close to your description.

> One guy is martial expert, another is tactician. The story revolves
> around the tactician and he's really weak.

Comment: No it is not The Star of the Overlord. The girl has pink hair I think. It was a school students manhwa